# jQuery prevent anchor click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, onclick

I'm trying to prevent the default anchor link and onclick event to trigger.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://google.com" 
    onclick="window.location.href='http://google.com.au'; return false;">
Google</a>
```

I'm trying to prevent any redirects from occurring, using the following jQuery code:

```
$("#mylink").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The code still invokes the anchor onclick event and redirects to http://google.com.au

Any clues or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear `onclick` manually, as long as it is being called **before** `.click()` callback:

```
$("#mylink").prop('onclick', null);
```